# Android Service issues in 4.3

Tags: android, android-service, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Since the Android 4.3 update I have been noticing some weird issues with Android services, I had previously built a service that grabs a users twitter statuses, stores them in a sqllite database and notified the user that they had gotten new tweets, this worked fine for months but since the Android 4.3 update its completely stopped working entirely, I also notice that other well established apps like my facebook messenger for instance has stopped sending me updates, ill wind up finding out someone messaged me when I log in through a browser a day or 2 later, I never used to have this issue before the update either, I dont think this is a coincidence, has anyone else been experiencing these issues?

Comment: Somebody voted to close this? you cant be serious? this is real issue.

Comment: What specific problems are you running into?